Simulation of water in a bottle
how do I do a simulation of water in a bottle. So that it turns over there relative to the position of the bottle. Thanks)

Hello, what does the fluid simulation give?

You should provide context and tell us what this is for. Show some images and screenshots of what you have and try to describe what you are after, maybe show some examples of what would be an acceptable result. The answer depends on what you need. It's possible to just simulate the level of the water changing, it's also possible to simulate water splashing around.

Hello, Паоло, welcome.  .. there are lots of ways to fake/simulate this.. which to chose will depend on the style of your result. Please include an illustration of  the kind of water and bottle you want to create, indicate whether the water should splash, or just remain level, etc. Your description turns out to be not specific enough.
